# Generate named bundle JS in rollup

Tags: rollupjs

I have a build requirement that requires each and every component to be built independently, I found out that I can have a multi input using the plugin [here](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/multi-entry) . The problem is, a single bundle.js is generated. I want to if possible retain file name in bundle directory. For example, `ComponentA.cy.ts` should have a corresponding bundle `ComponentA.js` in my bundle directory. Please is there any way I can achieve this ? Any help will be appreciated. Below is my rollup config

```
export default {
    input: ['cypress/support/component.ts', 'src/**/*.cy.jsx'],
    output: {
        dir: 'cypress/temp/',
        format: 'cjs',
        inlineDynamicImports: true,
        entryFileNames: '[name].js',
    },
    plugins: [
        resolve({ extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx'] }),
        postcss({
            plugins: [postcssNesting],
            writeDefinitions: true,
            modules: true,
        }),
        typescript({
            tsconfigOverride: {
                compilerOptions: {
                    declaration: false,
                    declarationDir: 'dts',
                },
            },
        }),
        commonjs(),
        dynamicImportVars(),
        multi({ entryFileName: '[name].js' }),
    ],
    external: [],
}
```